# がな and ておろうな at the end of sentence parts

Tags: translation

I have a following line of conversation:

> (1) 貴様ら…
>
> (2) 新しいオモチャではしゃぐのはよいがな
>
> (3) この躰の性能きっちりと把握できておろうな

Context: Three nonhuman inteligences have gotten their hands on some human bodies and now two of them are just fooling arround with them. The third one, their leader tells them the above (numbers are there just to number lines). Note, the leader is prone to using arhaic form from time to time. Things like ぬ instead of ない for negation.

I'm confused a bit with all these な endings. Like I get that the (2)nd line basically says:

> It's okay to play with your new toys

and the (3)rd one is something along the line of:

> Being able to properly grasp their abilities.

Now if the (2)nd didn't have that な I'd say that the が is connective but/and. But in the (3rd) one the entire bit できておろうな confusese me.

できる - be able to
できておる - being able to
できておろう - volitional form, aim to being able to? let's become able to?

As of now, I have it down as:

> You idiots…
> Playing with your new toys is fine, but...
> We should be getting a better grasp of these bodies’ abilities.

On the other hand, this kinda doesn't make sense, since fooling arround with them could count as getting a better grasp of them.

Sooo, what do you think, what did the leader mean by this, and what's up with all these な?!?

---

PS:

The subordinates reply by saying:

> Subordinate 1:
>
> もっちろん♪
>
> OF COURSE ♪
>
> Subordinate 2:
>
> 万全です
>
> Perfectly.

And while mochiron works, saying just perfectly to the above line makes my translation feel off. Allmost as if the leader actually said:

> fooling with them is fine, but have you properly grasped their abilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 新しいオモチャではしゃぐのはよいがな
>   この躰の性能きっちりと把握できておろうな

The first な is 間投助詞, or a filler.
<sub>It's 2⃣［間助］ in [デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/162229/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%AA/): `文末や、文中の種々の切れ目に用いる。語勢を添えて、自分の言葉を相手に納得させようとする気持ちを表す。「あの店はな、品物がいいんだ」「彼な、来られないんだって」`</sub>

You're right that the が is "but".

The second な is 終助詞, a sentence final particle. It's used to seek a response, agreement, or confirmation. Here in your example I think it's used for seeking confirmation.
<sub>It's 1⃣［終助］３－㋒ in デジタル大辞泉: `３ 活用語の終止形、助詞に付く。㋒相手の返答・同意を求めたり、念を押したりする意を表す。「君も行ってくれるだろうな」「早めに片付けような」`</sub>

できておろうな is a literary or old-fashioned way of saying できているだろうな. おろう is the volitional form of おる, and the volitional auxiliary う・よう can indicate 推量 (conjecture) as well as 意思 (volition). Here in your example it indicates 推量.
 <sub>It's used in the sense う［助動］３ in [デジタル大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/17145/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%86/): `３ 話し手の推量・想像の意を表す。「この仕事がかたづくのは夕方になろう」 ... [補説] ... 現代語では、3の場合、「今夜は雨が降るだろう（でしょう）」のように「だろう（でしょう）」を用いるのが普通で...`</sub>

「～～おろうな(？)」 is usually said as 「～～ているだろうな(？)」 in modern Japanese. It means "I suppose you've ~~, right?" → "You've ~~, right?"

So you can rephrase the sentence less literary like this:

> 新しいオモチャではしゃぐのはいいが(な)、
>   この躰の性能きっちりと把握できているだろうな。

Literally: "It's okay to get excited with the new toy, but (I suppose) you've properly grasped its ability, right?"

So you're right that the leader actually said:
"Fooling with them is fine, but have you properly grasped their abilities."

Answer (score 3):

な in both (2) and (3) is a sentence-end/filler particle which is essentially a masculine/authoritative version of ね for seeking agreement. So it's "you know" or "right?" depending on the context.

おろう is the "volitional" form of おる, but here it has the meaning of 推量 (inference/speculation/guess) rather than volition. (e.g., 真実だと言えよう = "(I believe) I could say it's true", 明日は雨となろう = "It shall rain tomorrow.") This is a fairly bookish and stiff expression but a certain type of fictional character may use this in speech.

> (3) この躰の性能(を)きっちりと把握できておろうな
>   (I suppose) You have (successfully) understood the performance of this body, right?

As for (2), I think your translation is already correct.

Comment: うわ、わたしらめっちゃおんなじこと書いてるぅ～  笑

Comment: 今までの最高記録は10秒差とかなのでこのくらいはよくありますw