# Understanding volitional form+はずがない

Tags: grammar

> 連邦の対〈レギオン〉戦術は徹底した部隊戦闘──一機の敵に複数名、複数機で相対する集団戦だ。いかに最新鋭の第三世代多脚機甲兵器〈ヴァナルガンド〉といえど、陸戦の支配者たる戦車型とやりあうには最低でも倍は要る。まして劣勢ともなれば、最早勝ち目など**あろうはずもない**。

86─エイティシックス─Ep.2 ─ラン・スルー・ザ・バトルフロント─〈上〉
安里アサト

I was taught that the verb that takes はずがない should be in dictionary form, as in this link.

https://www.edewakaru.com/archives/19456984.html

Why can はずがない follow volitional form? Is there any difference between volitional form+はずがない and dictionary form+はずがない?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/63091/5010

Answer (score 3):

う can mean simple future.

> ７ 実現の可能性がある意を表す。「足の遅い彼が一着になろうはずがない」→よう
>
> [大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%86/#jn-17145)

Here it means *it is **impossible there will be** any chance of winning*.

Comment: Thank you. But doesn’t ある also indicate future?

Comment: @chinoalpha Good point. Actually あるはずはない almost equally fits here. I guess it is similar in English (it is impossible there **is/will be** any chance). With shifting of the tense, it somewhat sounds more hypothetical. That is, the battle may not be real at the moment, but if it started, there will be no chance.

Comment: So あろうはずもない means あるであろうはずもない?

Comment: @JimmyYang Yes. In the latter, the second ある(あろ) is more である though.